# tensorflow fashion MNIST data set

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

Using the Fashion MNIST data set in Tensorflow.

When building the model as below, why is the flattened layer only (28*28=724) and not 724x60000? 60000 being the number of images in the dataset?

at what point is each image used in the model?

```
#flatten the images into a 1D array
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras. layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras. layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# Get the input shape of the Flatten layer
input_shape = model.layers[0].input_shape
print("Input shape:", input_shape)

# Get the output shape of the Flatten layer
output_shape = model.layers[0].output_shape
print("Output shape:", output_shape)
```

Comment: The neural network does not fit on every image at once. It fits a "batch", which is a small random selection from the dataset. This reduces memory usage and adds a small amount of randomness, which is helpful for getting out of local minimums.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the model fits on batch of images, which is a small selection from the dataset. If you look your result, you have:

```
# Flatten the images into a 1D array
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras. layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# Get the input shape of the Flatten layer
input_shape = model.layers[0].input_shape
print("Input shape:", input_shape)
>>> Input shape: (None, 28, 28)

# Get the output shape of the Flatten layer
output_shape = model.layers[0].output_shape
print("Output shape:", output_shape)
>>> Output shape: (None, 784)
```

You can see that the first dimension is `None` because your model doesn't know yet the batch size.

Imagine you set the batch size to 128, you will have 60000/128 batches of images, so the model will see ~468 batches of shape (128, 28, 28).